# An identity between integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, trigonometric-integrals

I want prove that, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$\rho > 1$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!\!
\frac{\sin^{n - 2\,}\left(\theta\right)}
{\left[\rho^{2} - 2\rho\cos\left(\theta\right) + 1\right]^{n/2}\,}\,\mathrm{d}\theta =
\frac{1}{\rho^{n - 2}\left(\rho^2-1\right)}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!\!\sin^{n - 2}\left(\theta\right)
\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
The hint is to use the following change of variable:
$$
\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}
{\left[\rho^{2} -
2\rho\cos\left(\theta\right) + 1\right]^{1/2}}
=
\frac{\sin\left(\alpha\right)}{\rho}
$$
But i can't go on.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin^n\theta}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{n/2}}=\frac{\sin^n\alpha}{\rho^n}$$
also:
$$\frac{\cos\theta}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{1/2}}-\frac{\rho\sin^2\theta}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{3/2}}=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\rho}\frac{d\alpha}{d\theta}$$
so if we try and put some of this substitution in (not a complete integral yet) we have:
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^n\alpha}{\rho^n}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$
if you take a look at the derivative above it has a relationship to the original function, so using this should be very helpful. Good luck